# How to edit a Tukey test plot in R

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, tukey

I carried out a post-hoc Tukey test on an ANOVA and then I made a plot of the results. I can't seem to change my x axis title or my y axis title. I get this error:

```
Error in plot.default(c(xi[, "lwr"], xi[, "upr"]), rep.int(yvals, 2L),  : 
  formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

This is my relevant code:

```
tuk <- TukeyHSD(final)
plot(tuk,xlab="Differences in mean departure times", ylab="Comparisons")
```

I also need to change the y axis tick mark labels but I don't know how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

So because of how they wrote the `plot()` method for `TukeyHSD` class object you can not change the axis labels by default, this detail is buried in the `?TuketHSD` man page.

But you can easily hack together a copy that does allow you to do it. First find  the code for the existing method with `getAnywhere(plot.TukeyHSD)`. Then adapt it like so:

```
tuk_plot <- function (x, xlab, ylab, ylabels = NULL, ...) {
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    xi <- x[[i]][, -4L, drop = FALSE]
    yvals <- nrow(xi):1L
    dev.hold()
    on.exit(dev.flush())
    plot(c(xi[, "lwr"], xi[, "upr"]), rep.int(yvals, 2L), 
         type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", main = NULL, 
         ...)
    axis(1, ...)
    # change for custom axis labels
    if (is.null(ylabels)) ylabels <- dimnames(xi)[[1L]]

    axis(2, at = nrow(xi):1, labels = ylabels, 
         srt = 0, ...)
    abline(h = yvals, lty = 1, lwd = 0.5, col = "lightgray")
    abline(v = 0, lty = 2, lwd = 0.5, ...)
    segments(xi[, "lwr"], yvals, xi[, "upr"], yvals, ...)
    segments(as.vector(xi), rep.int(yvals - 0.1, 3L), as.vector(xi), 
             rep.int(yvals + 0.1, 3L), ...)
    title(main = paste0(format(100 * attr(x, "conf.level"), 
                               digits = 2L), "% family-wise confidence level\n"), 
          # change for custom axis titles
          xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab)

    box()
    dev.flush()
    on.exit()
  }
}
```

Now you can adjust the x and y axis along with custom y-labels:

```
tuk_plot(tuk, "Hello X Axis", "Hello Y Axis", c("One", "Two", "Three"))
```

[image]

If you don't provide the y-labels the default ones from the model will show up.

Reproducible Example:

```
fm1 <- aov(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks))
tuk <- TukeyHSD(fm1, "tension")
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. How can I increase the font size of the axis labels within this code?

Comment: Since this is base R plotting you'd modify the maginifaction of the axis labels with `par(cex.lab= )`, anything above 1 will increase